# Cannot pass struct to function by reference

Tags: c

I'm creating a very simple dictionary structure in C and I'm not able to properly pass it to `dictAdd` function by reference. Something goes wrong inside the function and structure values get corrupted. See screenshots below. Everything is fine when I step into line 18, but when I get inside the function to line 19 the structure fields being to show inappropriate values.

**Line 18**

[image: Line 18]

**Line 19**

[image: Line 19]

**Dictionary.h**

```
typedef struct DictionaryStruct
{
    int *arr;
    int arrLen;
} Dictionary;

Dictionary *dictCreate(int arrLen);
int dictAdd(Dictionary *dict, char *key, char *val);
```

**Dictionary.c**

```
#include "Utils.h"
#include "Dictionary.h"

Dictionary *dictCreate(int arrLen)
{
    int *arr = createIntArray(arrLen);
    for (int i = 0; i < arrLen; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = '\0';
    }

    Dictionary dict;
    dict.arr = arr;
    dict.arrLen = arrLen;
    return &dict;
}

int dictAdd(Dictionary *dict, char *key, char *val) {
    int hash = getHash(key, dict->arrLen);
    dict->arr[hash] = val;
}
```

**Main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Utils.h"
#include "Dictionary.h"

int main() {
    Dictionary *dictPtr = dictCreate(5);
    dictAdd(dictPtr, "key1", "Hello");
    char *value1 = dictGet(dictPtr, "key1");
    printf("%s", value1);

    printf("Press any key to exit\n");
    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning a pointer to a local. Dereferencing a pointer after the end of its target's lifetime is *undefined behavior*.

Your `dictCreate` should heap-allocate the `Dictionary` structure as well (in addition to heap-allocating the `int` array).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I understand it now. Struct is being allocated in the stack memory